# Installing/Running Thin Webserver on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, thin

Having an issue running the "Thin" web server. It looks like installation was successful but when I run "thin start" It appears as though Thin starts to initialize but then cannot find some resources it needs.

Below, is the audit trail from my terminal session. Can someone offer a hand with this? According to the Thin docs, installation was done correctly. Thanks

**Rails 3.2.12

ruby 1.9.3**

```
root@pgateway:/var/www/testapp# gem install thin

Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: daemons-1.1.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: thin-1.5.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.0
Successfully installed daemons-1.1.9
Successfully installed thin-1.5.0
3 gems installed



root@pgateway:/var/www/testapp# thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends   /tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect': cannot load such file -- thin/connection (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:55:in `block in start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/thin:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: yes, webrick starts up fine when I do "rails s"

Comment: did you add it to the gemfile?

Comment: oops, no. The installation steps did not mention that.

Comment: that seemed to fix the issue. please post as an answer and I will select it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You seem to install thin separate from rails

Add it to your gemfile and you should be fine

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a gem, it must be in your Gemfile. You can solve your problem as follows:

- Add the following line to your **Gemfile**: `gem 'thin'`
- Update your current app's environment: `bundle install`
- Then start server

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following command:

cd to/your/rails/app

echo 'gem "thin"' >> Gemfile

thin start

this content from https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/115